# OCaml Project Directory Structure

Tags: ocaml

I would like to give two .ml sources files the same name in different directories in my source tree, but the OCaml documentation states that the a file A.ml is exported as a toplevel module A = struct ... end. If I have two files X/A.ml and Y/A.ml, how can I refer to them both from B.ml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules can contain modules, i.e. you can have a hierarchy of modules.
From the B.ml point of view, you can see two modules named `X.A` and `Y.A` .
They can even both have a function named `foo`, those functions would be seen as `X.A.foo` and `Y.A.foo` .

Beware that if you `open` both modules `X` and `Y`, the module `A` from `Y` will hide the module `A` from `X`.

That was from the namespace point of view. Now, about the source tree.
One way would be to have those files:

- x.ml
- X/a.ml
- y.ml
- y/a.ml

The file x.ml is automatically generated and contains just this:

```
module A = struct
(*The contents of x/a.ml is included here*)
end
```

Likewise for y.ml
There are several preprocessors able to include a file: cpp, camlp4, camlp5, camlmix...

This set of automatically generated files (and regenerated each time the source changes) is not very satisfiying, I will look at other answers.

You can also have a look at `ocamlc -pack`, but when I tried it a long time ago there was a problem with `ocamldoc` unable to have x/a.ml and y/a.ml . So check this before you settle on a tool.

Comment: So for clarification: without a preprocessor, all file names in the source tree must be distinct?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link modules with the same name into the same program. For example, extensions to the standard library, such as Batteries and Core, are forced to give standard modules a different name. In Batteries, the List module is called BatList. Then, they provide a wrapper module Batteries, within which the module is renamed with by doing `module List = BatList`. The overall path to this module is `Batteries.List`, so there is no clash with the Standard Library's top level `List`. Finally, the recommended way of using Batteries and Core is to do `open Batteries` and `open Core`, thereby giving you access to their additional list functions under the module name `List`.

Thus the only option is to rename your modules, but you can do this in two ways:

- Change the base names of the modules, e.g. call them A and B.
- Put the modules under another module, e.g. name them X.A and Y.A. If you want to keep your current directory structure, you can use OCaml's -pack option. Personally, I find this option too restrictive and always end up doing *manual packing*, i.e. the technique described above used by Batteries and Core.